# Is update() function and with_for_update() compatible with each other in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-update, race-condition

I have a database table which is constantly updated with new data by multiple people simultaneously. This changes include changes such as increasing and decreasing value of a cell by 1 and changing value of rows based on old values.

I have written all database functions and it is working correctly for single user. I now want to ensure that this will not create a race condition or such when used by multiple users. During my research I found an article which mentions 2 ways to avoid a race condition.

1. To directly update the database without reading values from database, ex.,
   session.query(table1).update({"col1":col1 + 1})
   session.commit()
2. To read and then update a cell in database by using with_for_update(), ex.,
   rows = session.query(table1).with_for_update().all()
   for row in rows:
   row.col1 += 1
   session.commit()

Now, I already have some less complex update functions as the 1st solution. So I don't want to unnecessarily change that, thus I want to confirm that if functions with 1st solution would be compatible with 2nd solution. I have read descriptions in some places and it isn't clear that these both would work with each other and not lead to race condition if a function with 1st solution is updating the same cell the 2nd solution has read for update and visa versa.